# Prevent double-encoding when sending json with PHP curl

Tags: php, json, curl, escaping

When I send my json encoded array via

```
<?php

$data=array("Arzt"=>array("Kundennummer"=>"", 
    "Praxisname"=>"Praxis XY",
    "Vorname"=>"Test",
    "Nachname"=>"Test",
    # ...
));


curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic MTIzMTIzMS1CbGltdXM6clVja20yaVJxT0V2Y1ZTAb1IQUI='));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

When CURL sends this, it arrives at the server encoded like this (webservice log):

```
{"{\"Arzt\":{\"Kundennummer\":\"\",\"Praxisname\":\"Praxis XY\",\"Vorname\":\"Test\",\"Nachname\": .........
```

But expected is:

```
{"Arzt":{"Kundennummer":"","Praxisname":"Praxis XY","Vorname":"Test","Nachname": ..........
```

How do I prevent the double encoding of the JSON string in PHP curl?

Comment: json_encode() cannot create such a string, because it's not valid JSON (regardless of the double-encoding). You must be mistaken. How are you seeing / debugging this? Have you actually checked what `json_encode($data)` outputs in this PHP script? cURL certainly won't alter it. At a guess, maybe the receiving webservice is doing something to it before it logs it. Please ensure you provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Just `json_encode($data)` outputs the string correct, as expected

Comment: Guess: the receiving end doesn’t understand the data to be JSON but is interpreting it as regular form-encoded data, meaning it’s looking for `a=b` values. So it’s giving you the entire JSON string as a key in an object with an empty value (`{"{…}": ""}`)‽

Comment: OK. Well as we said then this is likely to be an issue related to how the webservice is treating it when it arrives. cURL does not modify the data. (If you want to verify that, use something like Fiddler or wireshark to monitor the outgoing network traffic and look at the http request the curl code generated. Putting curl in verbose mode may also be useful for that too.). deceze may be onto something- maybe the webservice is not set up to accept JSON data. Is the webservice also code that you wrote yourself?

Comment: No. I try to send data to another company

Comment: How are you obtaining the log entry, then? I think if you can do what I suggested above and demonstrate that you're sending the data in the way you think is correct, then it's up to the other company to suggest if they are logging it incorrectly or if - as deceze noted - you are maybe sending the wrong format altogether. Does the API have any documentation available? It would expect that it would tell you clearly whether you should send the data in JSON, or form-url-encoded format, or some other format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had called

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(...));
```

several times and thought, that each header is added, but infact only the last header is added to the call.

You have to add all headers to one array and use curl_setopt for CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER only once.

In this case the jon header was overwritten, so the receiving end didn’t understand the data to be JSON but is interpreting it as regular form-encoded data, meaning it’s looking for `a=b` values. So it’s giving you the entire JSON string as a key in an object with an empty value `({"{…}": ""})`

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you'd done that. Glad you fixed it!